# MonoDevelop not generating *.exe file

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I have a project which was created using Xamarin studio version 5.4 on a Mac that I opened in Ubunutu 14.04 using MonoDevelop 5.0.1. When I build the project in MonoDevelop a dll file gets created but not the *.exe file. The `OutputType` tag in the .csproj file says Exe. I've checked the output paths and they all seem to be correct. I've also tried creating a test project and that produced the *.exe file.

Are there any configuration changes to be done in the IDE to get it to build the *.exe file in the project I opened? How do I get it to work?

Comment: It should work. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: Do you want the whole project or just the .csproj file? I can't upload the project as it is proprietary.

Comment: `.csproj` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install mono with:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

It worked for me.